# Return a table of value by filtering those who have never been assigned to another

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

Quick question here. I have a DB with a few tables, not much, but they are linked with reference keys. Here is my problem:

- Return the `sigil` of the courses not yet taught by teacher whose name is `'Velvet' , 'Moise'`

I can easily write the request, but I can't seem to find the right logic behind it.

Here is what I tried :

```
SELECT g.sigil
FROM   GroupCourse g JOIN Professor p
       ON g.profCode = p.profCode
WHERE  p.name != 'Velvet' AND p.name != 'Moise'
```

It works like it should, but if I have other teachers teaching the course too, let's say `TRX1277`, it will only remove the one that `Velvet` and `Moise` taught. Not all of them. I want to show only those who haven't been taught by those 2.

**Table definition:**

*GroupCourse* :

- `Primary keys : sigil, codeSession`
- `sigil: CHAR`
- `noGroup : INTEGER`
- `sessionCode: INTEGER`
- `profCode: CHAR`

*Professor* :

- `Primary key : profCode`
- `profCode: VARCHAR`
- `firstName: VARCHAR`
- `lastName: VARCHAR`

At the moment, I am getting this :

```
-------
SIGIL
-------
MGT1130
JPR6790
TRX1277
POU3333
```

Moise has no courses registered. But Velvet has 2. MGT1130 and POU3333. The thing is, few other teachers does have those courses too. Therefore why I need to fin a way to make it look like this :

```
-------
SIGIL
-------
JPR6790
TRX1277
```

I know I'm missing a small thing, but I can't find it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution by @fa06 was close, but was excluding the rows taught by the prof, not courses that were never taught by either prof.

```
SELECT g.sigil
FROM   GroupCourse g 
WHERE  not exists (
     select 1 
     FROM   GroupCourse g1 
     JOIN   Professor p ON g1.profCode = p.profCode 
     where  g.sigil=g1.sigil 
     and    p.name in('Velvet','Moise')
 )
```